# Select child elem separately via xpath 1.0

Tags: xpath

I would like get text values from table's td separately as below

```
//div[@id='foo']//table[contains(@class,'moo')][1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()
//div[@id='foo']//table[contains(@class,'moo')][2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()
```

But above queries give me same result.

```
<html>
    <body>
        ....

        <div id="foo">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <table class="moo"><tbody><tr><td>text1</td></tr></tbody></table>
                    <table class="moo"><tbody><tr><td>text2</td></tr></tbody></table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because each `td` has the same value `"text1"`?

Comment: @Andersson I edited my post. That was my fault. No each `td` value is different.

Comment: Now each expression returns different output as expected

Comment: @Andersson No I tested codes. Each `td` gives same result `text1`

Answer (score 0):

OK I found solution as below;

```
(//div[@id='foo']//table[contains(@class,'moo')])[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()
(//div[@id='foo']//table[contains(@class,'moo')])[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()
```